# Migration from hibernate-jpa-2.0-api to hibernate-jpa-2.1-api

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

Currently I am using Spiring data jpa with 2.0 JPA version. And I am looking into migrating from **hibernate-jpa-2.0-api** to **hibernate-jpa-2.1-api**, as version **2.1** contains some very useful features.

My question is following: Are there any risks doing this migration? For e.g: maybe JPA 2.1 version deprecates some method from 2.0 version.

Please, tell if there is something, that I should pay attencion.

Current Hibernate dependencies:

```
<!-- ***************************************************** -->
            <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.7.Final</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: You should specify which versions of hibernate-core or hibernate-entity-manager you're changing instead, because this is far too vague. If you plan on upgrading just the `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` artifact, that wouldn't change much. It's just the abstraction layer. Upgrading `hibernate-entitymanager` (or core, which replaces it in 5.2) would should refer to the migration guides https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/wiki/Migration-Guides

Comment: @coladict. Thanks. I have updated the question

Comment: I had to update several environments and I had no compatibility problem, luck